# User cannot create file linux

Tags: linux

may I know a command for root to change the mode to make the user able to create files. 
I tried multiple times but I can seem to solve it.

```
[root@master ~]# useradd -d /opt/hadoop hadoop
useradd: cannot create directory /opt/hadoop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the permissions on /opt/hadoop? If you created the directory manually as root then it's probably owned by root and the user has no access to it - you'd need to chown -R it to the correct ownership.

```
chmod 755 /opt
chown root /opt
chmod 755 /opt/hadoop
chown -R user:user /opt/hadoop
```